# MS Access replace part of file name with current directory

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to use MS Access to make a simple database of the store I work in and I have to insert photo's and I'm doing so by having a column where the filepath is stored eg. "C:\User\WL\Documents\Databasefolder\Pictures\img_xxxx.jpg" but when I hand over the file to my boss, the filename will be wrong as he will put it in a different folder. 
So I'm looking for somekind of function that changes the "C:\User\WL\Documents\Databasefolder" to the current directory of the database with included pictures. I have almost no experience with SQL or Access alltogether, hence I came here.

Comment: Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Pictures\"

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the path for the user's `Documents` folder like this:

```
DocFolder = Environ("HOMEDRIVE") & Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\Documents"
```